# How to search for neighbors given a coordinate in 2D arrays

Tags: java

I am trying to count the number of 1s in the neighboring cells in this 2D array. My approach is to check for every cell that is within the range and exclude the impractical ones through the conditional statement.

```
public static int countMines(int [][] mines, int myR, int myC)
{

  int r;
  int c;
  int count = 0;

  for(r = myR - 1; r <= myR + 1; r++)
     for(c = myC - 1; c <= myC + 1; c++)
        if( r >= 0 && r < mines.length && c >= 0 && c < mines.length 
                            && r != myR && c != myC && mines[r][c] == 1)
           count++;


  return count;         

}
```

This is the code I have so far. It accepts the 2D array and the coordinate of the cell you want to search its neighbors. But it DOES NOT work as I intend it. For example,

When `countMines(m, 0,0)` is called with `m` being as follows

```
[1] [0] [1] [1] 
[1] [0] [1] [1] 
[0] [0] [1] [0] 
[1] [1] [0] [0]
```

the method return `0`, as oppose to `1`.

Please tell me if this isn't clear enough. Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your clause `... && r != myR && c != myC && ...`.

You intend to avoid the `(myR, myC)` cell, but this will avoid all cells in the row `myR` and all cells in the column `myC`.

This should instead be changed to:

```
... && !(r == myR && c == myC) && ...
```

Or through De'Morgan's laws:

```
... && (r != myR || c != myC) && ...
```

That way, it will check so long as *both* values are not equal to the skipped values, opposed to if *either* value is.

---

An alternative would be utilizing a delta-values array such as:

```
private static final int[][] DELTA = new int[][]{
        {-1, -1},
        {0, -1},
        {1, -1},
        {1, 0},
        {1, 1},
        {0, 1},
        {-1, 1},
        {-1, 0}
};
```

Then using a single loop to access each offset.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering.  I actually JUST figured it out and it works.  I was so upset I printed out my work and followed the program and found the bug.  Thank you tremendously tho

Answer (score 1):

Without using any loops, you could use:

```
int count = 0;


// Check left of cell
if(myC > 0 && myC < mines.length)
    count += mines[myR][myC - 1]


// Check right of cell
if(myC >= 0 && myC < mines.length -1)
    count += mines[myR][myC + 1]


// Check top of cell
if(myR > 0 && myR < mines.length)
    count += mines[myR - 1][myC]


// Check bottom of cell
if(myR >= 0 && myR < mines.length -1)
    count += mines[myR + 1][myC]
```

Comment: Avoiding repetitive code is the sole purpose of a loop. And if for example he needs to change something, with this he'd have to change it in 8 different places.

Comment: I think this solution is more readable though and also more efficient. But I understand your point @Obicere, it is more code and therefore less maintainable.

Comment: When you only have to change 4 cells neighboring the parameter cell passed into the function and you know their locations, I do not think it is a good idea to iterate through the entire matrix. e.g. what if the matrix was 1000 x 1000.